# Am I correctly allocating memory for my pointer arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I am trying to track down a bug a big program. I think it is due to how I am passing arrays to my functions. Am I doing this correctly?

```
main(){
    int *x = declarArray(x, 100);
    int *y = declarArray(x, 100);

    // lines of code....

    x = arrayManip(x, 100);

    // more code...

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        y[i] = x[i];

    //more code...

    free(x);
    free(y);

}
```

This is how I manipulate arrays:

```
int *arrayManip(int *myarray, int length){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
        myarray[i] = i;
    return array;
}
```

This is how I initialize the arrays:

```
int* declareArray(int *myarray, int length){
    myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int*));
    if (myarray==NULL)
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
        myarray[i] = -888;
    return myarray;
}
```

This code seems to work fine on a small scale, but maybe there is a problem once I have many more arrays of larger size that are often getting passed back and forth and copied in my program?

Comment: You sure this even compiles? `myarray` is undefined in `arrayManip()`. Writing an [`sscce`](http://sscce.org/) may even help you avoid the need to post a question.

Comment: `myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int*));` is wrong; you want `length` integers, not `length` pointers. Use `myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int));` instead (without the *). This shouldn't be the cause of a crash though, as i wouldn't know of any current mainstream hardware where the size of a pointer is less that the size of an integer.

Comment: Explain to us what's going on? What's not working? Is there any error message?

Comment: Wow, amount of same answers about one bug found by @GuntramBlohm is amazing...

Comment: with this here `main(){ int *x = declarArray(x, 100); `  you are using x when it is not yet declared so that will not compile.

Comment: Of course it will compile - which does not mean it makes any sense. Fortunately, declarArray ignores its first parameter, so the un-initialized value is never used.

Comment: There are some errors that you probably introduced when preparing the example (you really should test run the code you post), but other than that I see no errors here that would cause the program to not work. The error is likely to be elsewhere. Try to prepare a minimal, working example that still shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

declarArray :

1. Name is not gramatically correct
2. The name of the function is not what it does
3. malloc with sizeof(int*), not sizeof(int). Guarantuee to be a bug in 64 bit machine
4. malloc fails, you print, but still write to null
5. passing myarray as argument is a noop as is
6. -888 is a magic number
7. There is no error check whatsoever

My advice. Throw it away and start fresh

Comment: You're right, but as he's debugging a big program, he'd probably have to throw away everything, and i severely doubt the 2nd effort will be significantly better than the first one.

Comment: I was talking about throwing away `declarArray`.

Answer (score 1):

No, as per my understanding.
You allocating one dim array => elements in that array should be integers and not pointers to integers so instead of this :

```
myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int*));
```

it should be :

```
myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int));
```

In function arrayManip you pass param named array, and than you trying to access it as myarray

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int*));
```

allocates an array of `length` pointers to an integer, but then puts it into a pointer to an integer (i.e. an array of integers, not pointers to integers). If you want an array of integers, you want:

```
myarray = (int*) malloc(length*sizeof(int));
```

or (if you want to zero it):

```
myarray = (int*) calloc(length, sizeof(int));
```

which does the size x length calculation itself.

To allocate a list of pointers to integers, you want:

```
myarray = (int**) malloc(length*sizeof(int*));
```

or

```
myarray = (int**) calloc(length, sizeof(int*));
```

Unless you are fantastically concerned about speed, I find using calloc() results in fewer bugs from uninitialized arrays, and makes the reason for the allocated size more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

The pointer is of word size [2 or 4 ,... depending on machine architecture]. whatever it may point to int,double,float,...

for integer pointer it works if it takes 4 bytes for int in machine. when u go for other data type it 'll lead you to error.

you should allot memory as

```
pointer = (DataType*) malloc (length * sizeof(DataType));
```

use malloc and to make your code clear.

```
 void* malloc (size_t size);
```

[malloc reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

use memset to allot default value [-888] for your array.

```
void *memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)
```

Comment: @zoska: thanks for pointing out the mistake [not just downvoting]. helps everyone to learn.